# Django - pass multiple HTML form inputs into a view

Tags: python, django, forms, python-requests, get

I have 3 form inputs that will be submitted when one master button is clicked to then be passed into a view as the request parameter. I would like to get the values of first_name, last_name and email inside my view using request.get(). When the button is clicked the values inside my form appear as **None**

HTML:

```
<div id="form_content">
    <form action="" method="post">
        <section class="form_inputs">
            <label for="first_name">First Name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="first_name">
        </section>

        <section class="form_inputs">
            <label for="last_name">Last Name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="last_name">
        </section>

        <section class="form_inputs">
            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input type="text" id="email">
        </section>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

views.py

```
def home(request):
    form_response = request.GET.get("form_content")
    print(form_response)
    context = {"title": "Home"}
    return render(request, "myApp/home.html", context)
```

Comment: assign name attribute for each input and get each of them seperately

Comment: Just, you need to change form method like this <form action="" method="get"> and set each of input names.

Answer (score 0):

In your input tags, you have not passed the `name` parameter. Pass the `name` parameter in your input tags, as Django collects the data from the name tags.

For example, in your case, it must be:

```
<input type="text" id="id_first_name" name="first_name">
<input type="text" id="id_last_name" name="last_name">
<input type="text" id="id_email" name="email">
```

Answer (score 0):

first you need to add **csrf_token** in your code for post method and also give a name for each input like this :

```
<div id="form_content">
    <form action="" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %} 
        <section class="form_inputs">
            <label for="first_name">First Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name">
        </section>

        <section class="form_inputs">
            <label for="last_name">Last Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name">
        </section>

        <section class="form_inputs">
            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email">
        </section>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

**and then**:

```
def home(request):
    first_name = request.POST['first_name']
    last_name = request.POST['last_name']
    email = request.POST['email']
    print(first_name, last_name, email)
    context = {"title": "Home"}
    return render(request, "myApp/home.html", context)
```